# Django request Post json

Tags: json, django, post, django-views, httprequest

I try to test a view, I receive a json request from the IPad, the format is:

```
req = {"custom_decks": [
        {
            "deck_name": "deck_test",
            "updates_last_applied": "1406217357",
            "created_date": 1406217380,
            "slide_section_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "deck_id": 1
        }
          ],
    "custom_decks_to_delete": []
}
```

I checked this in jsonlint and it passed.

I post the req via:

```
response = self.client.post('/library/api/6.0/user/'+ uuid +
'/store_custom_dec/',content_type='application/json', data=req)
```

The view return "creation_success": false

The problem is the post method in view doesn't find the key custom_decks.

```
QueryDict: {u'{"custom_decks": [{"deck_id": 1, "slide_section_ids": [1], 
"created_date":1406217380, "deck_name": "deck_test"}], 
"custom_decks_to_delete": []}': [u'']}>
```

The problem is the post method in view doesn't find the key custom_decks.
Because it is converting my dict to QueryDict with one key.

I appreciate all helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You're posting JSON, which is not the same as form-encoded data. You need to get the value of `request.body` and deserialize it:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
custom_decks = data['custom_decks']
```

Comment: The request (req), it's written directly in the test method, and it's a dictionary, I cant use req.body. How I proceed? thanks

Comment: That comment makes no sense. You post a dictionary: it is received as JSON which you must decode. If that code does not work, you should show the error you receive.

Answer (score 7):

As I was having problems with getting JSON data from HttpRequest directly with the code of the other answer:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
custom_decks = data['custom_decks']
```

error:

```
the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

***Here is an update of the other answer for Python version >3:***

```
json_str=((request.body).decode('utf-8'))
json_obj=json.loads(json_str)
```

Regarding decode('utf-8'), as mention in:

RFC 4627:

> "JSON text shall be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>   UTF-8."

I attached the Python link referred to this specific problem for version >3.

http://bugs.python.org/issue10976

Answer (score 3):

`python 3.6` and `django 2.0` :

```
post_json = json.loads(request.body)
custom_decks = post_json.get("custom_decks")
```

[`json.loads(s, *, encoding=None,...)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads)

> Changed in version `3.6`: `s` can now be of type `bytes` or `bytearray`. The input encoding should be `UTF-8`, `UTF-16` or `UTF-32`.

From `python 3.6` **NO need** `request.body.decode('utf-8')` .

Answer (score 2):

Since [HttpRequest has a read() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.read) loading JSON from request is actually as simple as:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    import json
    data = json.load(request)
    return JsonResponse(data=data)
```

If you put this up as a view, you can test it and it'll echo any JSON you send back to you.