# POST parameters formatted as JSON

Tags: python, django, sharepoint

I am writing a web service using Django that will be consumed from a MS SharePoint workflow. In the SP workflow, I created a dictionary with 2 items (id:1, text:'foo'), and used this dictionary as the request content. However, instead of using the dictionary to format a traditional POST parameter list, it sends it as a JSON object in the body of the POST request, so instead of the expected:

```
id=1&text=foo
```

in the body of the request, there is this:

```
{"id":1,"text":"foo"}
```

which of course, in turn, does not get parsed correctly by Python/Django (I am not sure who exactly does the parsing). How can I either get it to parse JSON, or get SharePoint to send traditionally encoded POST parameters?

**EDIT**
I saw other posts that explain how to get the raw body and parse the JSON. I was looking for a solution that would either:

1. Make SharePoint send normal data, or
2. Get Django to respect the `Content-type` header that states the data is JSON

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django request Post json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958705/django-request-post-json)

Comment: please do some search before asking - this as already been asked quite a few times here (last time was this morning FWIW) and it takes =~ 1.27 second to get the answer with google.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any parsing at the framework level. The body of the post request is always available in `request.body`, so you can access it directly:

```
result = json.loads(request.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you bit more to handle.

```
import json
import urlparse

json.dumps(urlparse.parse_qs("id=1&text=foo"))
```